# Change in lasso coefficients when subset of the feature set is used

Tags: lasso

Model 1 : Suppose I have a feature set {feature 1,feature 2,feature 3, feature 4} and a target, and I use lasso regression to build a predictive model. Now suppose feature 1,2,4 got non-zero coefficient in lasso model but 3 was excluded by lasso.

Model 2 : I run a lasso, now with the same feature set excluding feature 3

The qn is will or will I not get the same set of coefficients as I got in model 1.

My intuition says I will get the same coefficients,because

if L(a1, a2, a3, a4) = ( loglike - lambda * penalty )

then L(Model 1 coeff set) >= L(Model 2 coeff set with 0 for feature 3 coeff)
and reverse inequality is also true, given the fact that Model 1 chose 0 as coefficient of feature 3. So, assuming unique solution for argmax L exists the coeff set should match. Now evidently I am wrong as I ran lasso model and found out that coefficients differ even if you exclude features with 0 coefficients. So, someone please tell me what I am missing.

Thanks in advance...